# How do I store / pass inputs from dynamically made textfields in HTML to Django?

Tags: javascript, html, django

I'm dynamically creating new textfields which will take information from a user. I'm wondering how I'm supposed to go about taking the inputs and passing it to Django?

Comment: You need to show some code. Why is getting data from a dynamic field any different from any other field?

Comment: I have a limited understanding of web development, so I couldn't exactly figure out what to do. Right now I'm trying to work with JSON objects and AJAX and I ran into another problem! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55785104/name-of-json-object-appears-in-json-itself-when-passed