# Name of JSON object appears in JSON itself when passed?

Tags: python, jquery, html, ajax, django

Very new to webdev stuff

I'm trying to pass a JSON object to Django via AJAX, but the name of the JSON object I'm trying to pass keeps showing up in the data of the object itself.

Wondering what I can do to fix this?

```
jsonObj = {"pan":"cakes", "soy":"sauce"};                
$.ajax({
    url: "/AddItem",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        jsonObj
    },
```

```
def AddItem(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        QueryDict = request.POST
        q = dict(QueryDict.lists())

        print (q)
```

q shows up printed as

```
{'jsonObj[pan]': ['cakes'], 'jsonObj[soy]': ['sauce']}
```

Any help would be appreciated, many thanks (:

Comment: Remove braces `{}` in ´data´ -> `data: jsonObj`

Comment: Wow haha, I was staring at that for WAY too long. Thank you man!